# Still getting error on "list index out of range"

Tags: python

basically i'm trying to find whether or not a list has the '007' in them. the output still spits out what i'm looking for but at the end i'm still getting "list index out of range" error. C&P jupyter and see for yourself. i know it has something to do with the huge ass if statement but i just dont see the issue, i'm basically just looking for '007' which if it doesn't it'd just skip its logic... is it my code or is it jupyter acting crazy?

```
def spy_game(nums):
    listy = []

    for x in nums:
        if x == 0 or x == 7:
            listy.append(x)

    print(listy)
    #compare listy indexes
    for x, y in enumerate(listy):
        if y == 0 and listy[x + 1] == 0 and listy[x + 2] == 7:
            print(True)
            break
        elif y == 7:
            print(False)

spy_game([1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 7, 5])
spy_game([1, 0, 2, 4, 0, 5, 7])
spy_game([1, 7, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0])
```

Comment: Think about what element `listy[x + 1]` and `listy[x + 2]` are trying to get when `x` is the last index in the list.

Comment: I don't understand, 'x is the last index in the list'? listy[x + 1] and the other one is just bumping the current position of listy's index by 1 and 2 more. 007 takes 3 indexes: listy[x] = listy[0] (due to 'enumeration') and listy[x + 1] = listy[1] and the other is listy[2] that would be comparing the 3 indexes of 007 already... I don't know what I'm missing...

Comment: As you iterate, `x` will equal to each index in the list. If you were iterating over the list `[1, 2, 3]`, `x` would be equal to `0`, `1`, then `2` (the three indices present in the list). When `x` is equal to 2 (the last index in the list), `x + 2` will be 4, but there is no fourth index in the list.

Comment: isn't that already mitigated when I put the 'break' function after the print(True)? as soon as I have the True printed, the for loop would stop... unless you're suggesting it keeps on going?

Comment: Your second and third lists don't contain a 007, so the break will never be reached.

Comment: huh? the 2nd does output 007 the last one outputs 700 but its too much of a headache atm, I just decided to go with this

def spy_game(nums):
    listy = [str(x) for x in nums if x == 0 or x == 7]
            
    newWord = ''.join(listy)
    
    if '007' in newWord:
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
    

spy_game([1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 7, 5])
spy_game([1, 0, 2, 4, 0, 5, 7])
spy_game([1, 7, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0])

Comment: If the rules are that it can contain 007 *with other numbers between* then neither your original code nor the accepted answer work

Comment: @thundergawd Only the first contains a consecutive 007. The second has numbers in between, which your code isn't accounting for. I agree with Simon. Your code and the accepted answer will only address cases where there's a consecutive 007 with nothing in between. If only consecutive count, you could have just changed the loop line to `enumerate(listy[:-2]):`. You don't need to check the last two elements if the third last isn't a 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
L = [1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 7, 5]

if "007" in "".join([str(x) for x in L]):
     # There is a 007 in the list
```

Comment: a smart man you are, just implemented in a slightly different way but got the job done, forgot all bout them ''.join(x) function lol